# how to detect touch on a sprite in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

Is there any touches began function in windows phone XNA?
Here I am using a Texture2D and I want to detect the tap on it.
How to do that in xna?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `TouchCollection` class and set a TouchLocation for your Texture2D

Get it's state via:

```
TouchCollection touch = TouchPanel.GetState()
```

Then iterate over the TouchLocations in your collection, i guess this will be your texture2D's position:

```
foreach(TouchLocation tl in touch)
```

Then inside this loop you can check if the location was touched via the `State` property of `tl` e.g.

```
if(tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
{
    //Execute your code here
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample code? I am not used to C# kind of programming. it will be helpful.

Comment: The sample code above is enough to get you started. 

The position of your `Texture2D` object will be your touch location, add this to the touch collection (named touch as above) and then iterate over the collection checking each tl:

`if(tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
{
    //Execute your code here
}`

Then when a touch is recorded you can call your code to do whatever it is you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

We wrote our own button class and made certain sprites inherit from this button class. Pretty good way to go about it since the entire sprite then acts as a button.